# Pre-flop charts 6-max cash games

Tags: online, poker-theory, cash-game, strategy, poker-tools

I am planning on building a poker bot. The first and easiest part is the pre-flop strategy. Do you guys have any links for a good pre-flop strategy in NLH 6-max cash games, 100BB deep? This includes:

1. Opening ranges
2. Flat, 3-bet and perhaps 4-bet strategies
3. BB defending ranges

Even one of the three mentioned above would be really helpful.

Comment: There's some info [here](http://www.beat6max.com/preflop.html) and [here](http://www.pokergurublog.com/content/preflop-strategy-starting-hand-chart) which you might find useful. Also a decent thread on 2p2 started with [this post](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/showpost.php?p=2593230&postcount=1).

Comment: Thanks. 2 out of 3 were about limit hold 'em. I am sorry I didn't specify it was about no limit holdem. I updated that. Your second link is very helpful thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, sorry about that - I missed that 2 of them were LHE when I quickly dug out the links - glad I only posted a comment and not an answer! :)

Comment: @paparazzi how would you suggest me to rank the hands? Use flopzilla perhaps?

Comment: @paparazzi and I still don't understand what you mean by 'ranking the hands'. It is very vague. Quoting previous sentences will not help. Please explain if you will.

Comment: @paparazzi one last question: what program, ide and language did you use? My bot needs to control the mouse and analyse the screen, so would C#, .net and visual studio be a good choice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found some opening charts [here](http://www.acepokersolutions.com/files/6-max%20starting%20hand%20charts%20v3.pdf) which you might find useful:

## Semi-Loose

[image: LooseUTG]
[image: LooseMPCO]
[image: LooseBTNSB]

## Tight

[image: TightUTG]
[image: TightMPCO]
[image: TightBTNSB]

There is also a chart [here](http://www.pokerstrategybible.com/preflopstartinghandchartbasics.html) with calling, 3-betting and 4-betting ranges:

[image: 6MaxChart]

Answer (score 1):

### If you are here for more advanced preflop tips and to push further:

- Semi-loose is the best chart here, if you want to push your level, aim for it.
- Opening ranges vary with how deep you are. The deeper, the more polarized (i.e. more suited connectors and less QJ likes). 100bb deep it's considered stronger to raise pocket pair and suited connectors because of the deceptive value, than QJo KJo who can (will) be outkicked by callers.
- 3 betting light is best done with half decent hands, sometimes being on the call range and sometimes not, but on a randomized basis (e.g. 3-betting 96s and 20% of your KQo). 3-betting a hand like T3o is considered bad. The optimal frequency is roughly 1/3rd of your 3-betting range.
- Your response to a 3-bet should be a fold in 55-60% of cases. The remaining 40% are mostly calls. This *does* imply calling while being behind your opponent range, like for example calling KJo on the button while the BB have TT+ AQ+ half of the time. This **is hard** to make profitable, but you can't really fold more without exposing yourself to being exploited.
- 4 betting light is best done with an Ace or King as a blocker for AA AK KK. Optimal frequency is again 1/3 of total 4bets. If you don't like 4-betting light, then you are probably just as good not 4-betting at all. You certainly don't want your strongest range to be easily read.